# GCP Memorystore Redis: Protocol error, got "\x15" as reply type byte

Tags: redis, google-cloud-memorystore

I have been researching this Redis error for days now...

I created a GCP Memorystore Redis instance and received the following internal IP endpoint:

```
10.xxx.xxx.xxx:6378
```

I created a small GCE instance and made sure that zone matched the Redis instance:

```
us-central1-f
```

[image]

However, I when I ssh into the VM, connect to Redis, and issue a PING, I get the following error response

```
Protocol error, got "\x15" as reply type byte
```

[image]

Any idea why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the Redis instance was configured with an [AUTH](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/managing-auth) string and/or [TLS encryption](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/enabling-in-transit-encryption), you would need to pass these credentials when connecting to it.

I received the same error when using your command to connect to my encrypted instance. This can be done in two ways as far as I tested (from a GCE instance in the same VPC as Redis):

**1.** Using the redis-cli, you could use the following command to authenticate (see [here](https://redis.io/docs/manual/cli/#ssltls) for information on the flags used in the command):

```
redis-cli -h <ip_addres> -p <port> -a <auth_string> --tls --cacert <path/to/certificate_file.pem>
```

*Note: the certificate file would need to be [installed](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/enabling-in-transit-encryption#installing_a_certificate_authority_on_your_client) to your VM.*

**2.** The GCP Memorystore [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connecting-redis-instance#securely_connecting_to_a_redis_instance_using_stunnel_and_telnet) recommends using telnet and Stunnel to connect to a secured and encrypted instance.

Something not included in the documentation is that after running `telnet localhost 6378` in step 4, you would need to pass the AUTH string [in the telnet](https://redis.io/commands/auth/#:%7E:text=of%20the%20command%3A-,AUTH%20%3Cpassword%3E,-This%20form%20just) console:

```
AUTH <auth_string>
+OK
PING
+PONG
```

After that, you can PING the instance in step 5, skipping sending the AUTH string will return this error: `-NOAUTH Authentication required`. Besides that, you should follow as documented the rest of the steps.

Comment: thank you, attaching the AUTH string worked...

Comment: It will great if you could provide code snipet for java or nodejs or python to connect to my GCP Memorystore Redis instance from us-central1-f with TLS enabled.